# Content Store Query to List all fields in a framework model and the source

Tags: cognos

I'm looking to query the Content Store database to get a list of all fields in a specific framework model. I also require the source (Database.TableName.Field) of each field and also any calculation / transformation.

Is this possible?

Comment: Try doing a `Content Overview Report` from within Framework Manager. It will have a **lot** more information in it.  If there's a better way to get the information you're looking for, short of parsing the model.xml, I don't know it.

Comment: Used Framework Manager \Tools\Model Report to create an xml file with all the data I require. Found xsd file in \32bit\templates\bmt\Cr1Model.

Comment: I'm now tring to get the data into a database table.  I've tried SSIS but it does not support mixed content model on Complex Types.

Any suggestions?